# Unable to use WebBrowser Control inside a form that is Loaded from background Worker?

Tags: c#, .net, facebook-like, webbrowser-control, backgroundworker

I have a windows form application with Two forms, `Login` and `Account`

In the Login form, i have `backgroundWorker1`

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{

// doing some heavy work ...

Account acc = new Account(entered_username, entered_password, true);
acc.ShowDialog();
acc.Dispose();
}

//....
```

And `Button1`

```
//...

private void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        showOrHideLoading();
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();

    }

//...
```

When i click on button1, the Account form appears correctly but after adding a WebBrowser 
Control to the Account form, the application doesn't work as expected, and when i click on Button1, nothing happens!

Is there any limitation of using WebBrowser Control with BackgroundWorker ?

I need to display a link (to facebook like button) using WebBrowser, is there an alternative way to display html content inside Windows Forms Application without using WebBrowser control.

Comment: Why use a background worker just to show another form ?

Comment: Beacause i'm doing some heavy work (connect to sql, check whether account is confirmed, whether activated..etc) before displaying the form

Comment: See this other SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269800/webbrowser-control-in-a-new-thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have a good reason, try to always keep UI on the same thread.

Put your "heavy work" in the background thread and display a progress dialog or whatever.

Once that completes, THEN launch the web browser form.